# Getting "appcontent" location.host

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am not an expert JavaScript user and I am having difficulty with `addEventListener`.

```js
var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load, true);

function load(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
    alert(doc.location.host);
}
```

In an add-on this code will alert the `location.host` of the `appcontent`.  My problem is that I don't need an event listener and want to call load like a normal function:

```js
var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
load(appcontent);

function load(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
    alert(doc.location.host);
}
```

This is what I was trying to do but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `load()` function still expects an event but you are now passing the actual element to it. Also, which location do you want to know, that of the currently selected tab? Then you can use the global `content` variable, it is pointing to the `window` object of the current tab. So changing the `load()` function into something like this should work:

```
function load() {
    alert(content.location.host);
}
```

Use Ctrl+Shift+J to open JavaScript Console and to check the errors for your extension - it should help you find our what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir, this was semi-working but I was getting an error with content.body (where it would say body is null or undefined). I was able to come up with a solution to my problem. Kind of a long way around but it works.